# Python - Error importing PyQt-Modules in Linux

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4, ubuntu-16.04

I´m trying to run my script on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) but it fails to import the necessary modules from PyQt4 as you can see in the picture.

But when importing PyQt4 with "import PyQt4" it imports it without problems.

When testing on Windows 10, everything works fine.

Any idea where the problem could be? Thank you in advance :)

[image: The console output I receive when running my script GUI.py]

Edit: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you install PyQt4 for python2.7

Comment: Nop, I installed it for both Python 2 and Python 3, already checked and tested to import.
It works when importing with "import PyQt4" but not "from PyQt4 import QtGui".

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39577184/4041795) answer already? Might lead you to a solution. Short on time atm, might get back to this later.

Comment: @freedome97. After `import PyQt4`, what is the output of `print(os.listdir(os.path.dirname(PyQt4.__file__)))`?

Comment: @ekhumoro This comes in return: 
Edited above because of space reason ...

Comment: @freedome97. PS: I forgot to ask you to also give the output of `print(PyQt4.__file__)`. And you need to print all the output from within the script that is giving the error.

Comment: @ekhumoro I tried it with python 3.5 and it works o.O
Still weired that a error occurs with python 3.6.
Anyway I will edit it above

Comment: @freedome97. Not weird at all. You obviously installed PyQt4 for python-3.5 and not for python-3.6.

Comment: @ekhumoro But why can I then import PyQt4 when I´m under Python 3.6?
Anyway thanks for the help :D

Comment: @freedome97. Because the PyQt4 directory is just an empty package namespace, so importing it does nothing. If you look carefully at the output I asked for, you will see that the modules are all named `xxx-35m-xxx.so`. So they were compiled for python-3.5, not python-3.6.