# PyQt5 not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I get the following error

**ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore' from 'PyQt5' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/**init**.py)**

which makes me think that the module is not installed.

When I try to install it I get:

*pip3 install PyQt5*

**Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable**

**Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.14.1)**

I also tried the following and got

*sudo pip3 install PyQt5*

**Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.14.1)**

**WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv**

**WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.**

Any idea?
I am running python3.10 on Ubuntu

Comment: Do not try to "fix" things by randomly installing packages with pip. You already have the official ubuntu pyqt packages installed. What application did you run that produces that import error? And how did you install that application?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to launch your program with `python3 program.py` or `python program.py` depending on the one you already use ?

Also try to run a `pip3 list` to see if the module is installed.

You can try to install with `python3 -m pip install PyQT5` or just `python -m pip install PyQT5`

Answer (score 0):

you can try reinstalling

```bash
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall PyQt5
```

however I recommend using a virtual environment (e.g. using venv module) to install the modules and use them:

```bash
$ sudo apt install python3-venv
$ python3 -m venv my-project-env
$ source my-project-env/bin/activate
```

then install required modules in your project's virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to install/upgrade `matplotlib`.

source: [ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574639/importerror-cannot-import-name-qtcore)